# Does $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sin\left(\pi\sqrt[3]{n^{3}+1}\right)$ exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have this limit:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sin\left(\pi\sqrt[3]{n^{3}+1}\right)$$
I don't even know if it exists. If so, what its value ?
Really don't have any idea..

Comment: The limit of n^3 +1 as n goes to infinity is n^3. Take it from there.

Comment: You should be able to get a bound of the form $\sqrt[3]{n^3+1}\leq n+f(n)$ for some $f$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=0$. (Try factoring out $n$ from the root). What does this imply?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We have that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sqrt[3]{n^3+1}-n\right)=0,$$so 
$\pi\sqrt[3]{n^3+1}=\pi n+ \varepsilon_n,$ where $\lim\varepsilon_n=0$. Therefore
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sin(\pi\sqrt[3]{n^3+1})=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sin(\pi n+\varepsilon_n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sin\varepsilon_n=0
$$

Comment: The limit does not exist. How do you know $lim sin(\pi(n))=0$, n is not necessarily an integer.

Comment: Let $n$ go to infinity on the path $\frac{1}{2},\frac{5}{2},\frac{9}{2},\frac{13}{2},\frac{17}{2},...$ then $\sin(\pi n + \epsilon_n)=\cos \epsilon_n \to 1$.

Comment: To be absolutely correct it should be $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n\sin\varepsilon_n=\pm 0$, but the sign does not matter since it still is $0$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** When $n$ is even, we have:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sin\left(\pi\sqrt[3]{n^{3}+1}\right) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sin\left(\pi\sqrt[3]{n^{3}+1} - \pi n\right) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{...}\right)$$

Similarly, we can deal with the odd $n$ case and conclude the limit is $0$.

Comment: you should choose a specific convergence path so that this holds, or not?

Comment: this could be related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Irrationality_measure

Comment: @Math-fun Not sure why we'd need irrationality measure here, we could simply use $\displaystyle \sqrt[3]{n^{3}+1} -  n = \frac{1}{(n^3+1)^{2/3}+(n^3+1)^{1/3}n+n^2}$ which goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$

Comment: generally we do not have $\sin (f(n))=\sin(f(n)-\pi n)$.

Comment: @Math-fun ah! I see your point .. we consider the even $n$ subsequence and odd $n$ subsequence separately and show both converge to $0$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: $\pi\sqrt[3]{n^3+1}$ is continuous and $\lim_{x\to n\pi}\sin{x}=0$.

Comment: I don't see how the second limit applies , if $n$ is not necessarily an integer, may you please explain. @Kola B.